# remove whitespaces from text inside textarea

Tags: javascript, php, html, textarea

I have a textarea and inside it, looping through a unserialized array.

I am trying to take text inside of textarea, break the string into an array with new line spaces as a separator, and serialize the array and store back to database.

But with these spaces, I am getting a whole string as a single array element.

Here's my code:

```
$items = unserialize($menu['lunch_items']);

<textarea name="items" class="editInput items form-control input-sm" style="display: none; resize: none;" rows="8" cols="60"><?php foreach($items as $item) :?>
<?php echo $item; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?></textarea>
```

Its output:

```
                      Rice
Parbar Aalu saadheko bhuteko sab sab
Mix Curry (for veg)
Egg Curry (for non-veg)
Mula koreko with sano kerau
```

This is how I accessed the textarea value:

```
var items = $(this).closest("tr").find('textarea[name="items"]').val();
```

Here's how I get and try to break it into array:

```
$items = $postValues['items'];
print_r($items);

$itemArr = preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n/', $items);
$itemArr1 = explode('\n', $items);
print_r($itemArr);
print_r($itemArr1);
die();
```

Output in console:

```
Rice                                                            Parbar Aalu saadheko bhuteko sab sab                                                            Mix Curry (for veg)                                                         Egg Curry (for non-veg)                                                         Mula Koreko with sano kerau                         

Array
(
    [0] =>                              Rice                                                            Parbar Aalu saadheko bhuteko sab sab                                                            Mix Curry (for veg)                                                         Egg Curry (for non-veg)                                                         Mula Koreko with sano kerau                         
)
Array
(
    [0] =>                              Rice                                                            Parbar Aalu saadheko bhuteko sab sab                                                            Mix Curry (for veg)                                                         Egg Curry (for non-veg)                                                         Mula Koreko with sano kerau                         
)
```

What I want it to be:

```
Array
(
   [0] => Rice
   [1] => Parbar Aalu sadheko bhuteko sab sab
   [2] => Mix Curry
    .
    .
)
```

How do I properly strip white spaces keeping new line spaces intact, and break it into proper array?

Comment: You are looking for `trim()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove spaces from my php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42944462/how-to-remove-spaces-from-my-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your PHP-code, it would be reasonable to use the trim()-function after you generated the text-output. Because you have an array here, it is easier to work with array_map():

```
$itemArr = array_map('trim', $itemArr);
```

This results is giving you back all Array elements trimmed. After this you can also implode the array to a string which you can put directly in your textarea:

```
$itemArr = implode("\n", $itemArr);
```

To trim with JavaScript you can use the JavaScript-trim()-function:

```
var textarea = $(this).closest("tr").find('textarea[name="items"]');
    textarea.val(textarea.val().trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$itemsArr = explode("\n", $items) ;
```

Try this